# Different behavior between printf and fprintf

Tags: c, file-io

When I run the following code with a struct containing a name of hello and the date of today date:

```
typedef struct savedSite{
    char *siteName; 
    char *date; 
} SAVED_SITE;

void printSite(struct savedSite site){
    printf("Site: %s\nDate Added: %s\n",site.siteName,site.date);
    FILE *fpointer;
    fpointer = fopen("storage.txt","a");
    fprintf(fpointer,"Site: %s\nDate Added: %s\n",site.siteName,site.date);
    fclose(fpointer);
}

SAVED_SITE* makeNewSite(){
    SAVED_SITE* returnSite = malloc(sizeof(SAVED_SITE));
    returnSite->siteName = malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
    returnSite->date = malloc(sizeof(char)*25);
    printf("Enter Site Name: ");
    scanf("%20s", returnSite->siteName);
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
    char s[64];
    strftime(s, sizeof(s), "%c", tm);
    returnSite->date = s;
    return returnSite; 
}

int main() {   
    SAVED_SITE *newSite = makeNewSite();    
    printSite(*newSite);
    free (newSite);
    return 0;
}
```

I get a console output of:

```
Site: hello
Date Added: Sat Mar 18 16:37:12 2017
```

but a file output of:

```
Site: hi
Date Added: 0í
```

Why is this and how can I write to the file what it had in the console?
Edit: Added the rest of the program, but the printSite method is what I'm confused about.

Comment: How is `site` constructed?

Comment: You really only need a `main` method and a definition of `struct savedSite` to make this example complete. I will not vote to close this question, but please make the edits before somebody else does vote to close.

Comment: Once you respond to @merlin2011 by completing the example code, I suspect you may have initialized site.siteName and site.date as variables on the stack from a separate routine. That would explain why your struct gets trampled after a few function calls. If done correctly, the contents of the file should match the console output.

Comment: Try duplicating the first `printf()` line in your function.  I won't be surprised to find that the output is different between the two.  Probably, you have a structure containing a couple of `char *` elements, and you have those pointers pointing to memory that is no longer valid — it is being reused by functions such as `printf()` for various purposes.  It's a guess; it's a semi-plausible guess, though.  Also, please read up on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) — that's what people are asking for; a complete minimal program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @merlin2011: C does not support _methods_.

Comment: @olaf, Fair point. I noticed but didn't want to delete and repost the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `makeNewSite` you save the address of a local variable to be used later. Problem because later that address will have become invalid.

```
returnSite->date = s; // wrong
```

Try

```
strcpy(returnSite->date, s);
```